# Why does WebStorm throw 'Can't find stylesheet to import' when using the Sass file watcher?

Tags: css, sass, webstorm

I am importing a Sass file into my component with

```css
@import 'src/assets/sass/var'
```

In the browser everything is correct but WebStorm tells me:

> Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
>
> @import 'src/assets/sass/var'

home.component.**css** looks like this:

```css
/* Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
 *   ,
 * 1 | @import 'src/assets/sass/var'
 *   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 *   '
 *   home.component.sass 1:9  root stylesheet */

body::before {
  font-family: "Source Code Pro", "SF Mono", Monaco, Inconsolata, "Fira Mono",
      "Droid Sans Mono", monospace, monospace;
  white-space: pre;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  content: "Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.\a   \2577 \a 1 \2502  @import 'src/assets/sass/var'\d\a   \2502          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\a   \2575 \a   home.component.sass 1:9  root stylesheet";
}
```

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 1):

This error comes from the Sass compiler, not from the IDE itself.

---

Option 1 is to specify a valid relative path in import e.g. change the import to `@import "./path/from/your/file/var";`.

---

If you don't want to change the import, option 2 is to pass a [load path](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import#load-paths) to the compiler to get the import resolved by specifying the folder(s) the compiler should look for `.scss` file(s) in.

*WebStorm (2023.2.5)* > *Settings* > *Tools* > *File Watchers* > *SCSS watcher*

Edit the *arguments* setting to add the `load-path` argument i.e

```
--load-path ../../node_modules ...
```

[image]

Note that the folder path should be relative to the Sass compiler's working directory (*Working directory* setting) - WebStorm by default only looks inside the file directory.